# Taking limit on both sides of an equation

Tags: limits

If I take the limit on both sides of an equation, then does the equation still hold? Are there some exceptions?

I think it is totally possible and I know that it is a silly question, but I want to hear a concrete answer at least once.

Comment: ...presuming the limit exists?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Are you asking that if a two-sided limit exists, then does the limit exist?

Comment: Are you asking, for example, does $a_n=b_n$ imply$\lim a_n=\lim b_n$, or, for another example, does $f(x)=g(x)$ imply $\lim f(x)=\lim g(x)$?

Comment: If two functions are identical, they are substitutable so of course must have the same limit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If both limits exist, then they agree.

Suppose we have 
$$  A(x) = B(x)  $$
and we want to take the limit $x \rightarrow c$ where $c$ is either a real number, $\infty$, or $-\infty$.  We could take the limit on both sides, but instead, let's do this...  \begin{align*}
A(x) - B(x) &= 0  \\
\lim_{x \rightarrow c} (A(x) - B(x)) &= \lim_{x \rightarrow c} 0  \\
\lim_{x \rightarrow c} (A(x) - B(x)) &= 0
\end{align*}
We can split the limit on the left-hand side only if the two resulting limits exist. \begin{align*}
\lim_{x \rightarrow c} A(x) - \lim_{x \rightarrow c} B(x) &= 0  \\
\lim_{x \rightarrow c} A(x) &= \lim_{x \rightarrow c} B(x)  \text{,}
\end{align*}
again, if the two limits exist.

You might, fairly, ask how one limit might exist and the other not.  As an example, take $A(x) = \frac{1}{1-y}$ and $B(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\lceil x^2 + 1 \rceil} y^k$.  ($B$ may look weird, but it is just a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).  You've probably seen these many times before.)  For every $y$ in $(-1,1)$, $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} A(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} B(x)$.  But at $y = -1$, $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} A(x) = -1/2$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} B(x)$ does not exist.  This is because the summands are $1, -1, 1, -1, \dots$ and the sequence of partial sums is $1,0,1,0,1,0,\dots$, which sequence does not have a limit.

Comment: I don't understand your counterexample. How does that satisfy the premise $A(x)=B(x)$? If $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ are equal expressions for all $x$, then one can substitute one for the other, so of course they must have the same limiting value (this includes the case where the limit does not exist too).